# Jupyter notebook 500 error and Dataframe issues

Tags: pandas, anaconda, jupyter

I've been trying to launch jupyter notebook by using separately those 2 methods:

- terminal (pip install)
- anaconda3

Python 3.9 is installed on my iMac.
I'm using 2 accounts, `admin` and `user`.
Firstly I installed jupyter notebook **via terminal**, admin session: it worked but I couldn't use Dataframe after importing pandas. Except `Dataframe`, it was ok on the admin session but when I wanted to use it on user session. 500 internal server with those messages in terminal:

- `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'`
- `[E 21:46:34.933 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Untitled.ipynb?kernel_name=python3 (::1)`

I removed then jupyter notebook and its dependencies and installed anaconda3 BUT logged on user session. I tried to use jupyter notebook and jupyter lab and got kind of the same messages plus `host 8888 is not available`, `8889 not available` ...

I went through tens of messages from several web sites, tried to upgrade nbconvert, to understand permissions, PATH changes.... But it is really hard to find a solution.

When using Pycharm, there is no problem with `Dataframe`...

Comment: Welcome De716. Any particular reason you're installing with these multiple accounts? It almost sounds like you installed on the admin account, but are trying to launch on the user account? Could you confirm that?

Comment: hey! indeed I installed first jupyter notebook on admin and tried to launch on my user account. realized that it was ...silly and removed jupyter nb from admin (trying to removing everything). I installed then anaconda3 on my user account but I still get those warnings when I launch notebook via anacona navigator!!

Comment: is there any potential risk if I go back for an admin installation of jupyter nb via pip, in parallel with anaconda3 on my user account?

Comment: What OS are we talking about here? You should be able to do everything you want to do using a standard user account. This is based on my experience on Macos. I've also become less and less of a fan of Anaconda and generally just pip install everything and avoid `conda` like the plauge.